# Sql: select rows based on another table if is populated or empty

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables.
First is called TempIds and it contains only one column called Id which is of type int

TempIds:

```
Id
45
34
77
```

The second one is called Countries which has two columns, Id and Name
Countries:

```
Id      Name
22      Austria
45      Germany
88      China
12      Japan
```

What I want is to select all the rows from Countries table matching the Ids in the TempIds table. But the catch is, if TempIds is empty then the query should return all the rows from Countries.

So far this is what I have tried:

```
select *
from Countries c
left join TempIds t on c.Id = t.Id or t.Id is null


select *
from Countries c
left join TempIds t on c.Id = t.Id
where (c.Id = t.Id or t.Id is null)
```

Both of the queries above do not return the correct records. My question is, how can I write a query that will return the correct result. That is, based on current TempIds table I should only get Germany. But if TempIds is empty, then I should get all countries from Countries table.

Thanks is advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Very Basic but can be tried:->

```
SELECT c.* 
FROM 
   countries c LEFT OUTER JOIN tempids t 
      ON c.id = t.id
WHERE
   t.id is not null 
   OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tempids)
```

Another option:->

```
WITH CTE as 
(
   SELECT 
     c.id, c.name, t.id as t_id 
   FROM
      countries c LEFT OUTER JOIN tempids t 
         on c.id = t.id
)
SELECT * 
FROM CTE
WHERE
   t.id is not null
   OR NOT EXIST (
      SELECT 1 
      FROM cte 
      WHERE t_id is not null 
   )
```

Or very simple would be to Check the table count of tempid first then decide on the query:->

```
IF exists(select 1 from tempid)
BEGIN
  SELECT c.* 
  FROM 
     countries c INNER JOIN tempids t 
       ON c.id = t.id
END
ELSE
BEGIN
   SELECT * from countries
END
```

Please don't mind the formatting.

Comment: Thanks. I chose the first suggestion, because it is easier to use the same where clause in update statement as well.

Answer (score 0):

> select all the rows from Countries table matching the Ids in the TempIds table. But the catch is, if TempIds is empty then the query should return all the rows from Countries.

Sounds like you should write an IF condition checking for the scenario, and run appropriate query based on that.

Something like,

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TempIds t INNER JOIN Countries c ON c.ID = t.ID)
BEGIN
    -- TempIDs has at least one record that maps to countries.
    SELECT c.*
    FROM TempIds t 
    INNER JOIN Countries c 
    ON c.ID = t.ID
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM Countries
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `UNION` operator with `CROSS JOIN` to get the all countries if the TempIds has *null* values

```
SELECT c.id, c.name FROM Countries c
LEFT JOIN TempIds t on c.id = t.id
UNION
SELECT t.id, c.name FROM TempIds t, Countries c
WHERE t.id IS NULL
```

---